# Where should I store my secret keys for my Node.js app?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am really struggling as to how I should hide my keys.

The two keys I need to hide are secrets.crypto and secrets.jwt... I plan on hosting my application on AWS using Elastic Beanstalk.

Also I am not sure where I would put my keys for access to things like my Dynamodb and my S3 bucket.

```
exports.generateToken = (type, user) => {
    if (!_.isString(type)) {
        return undefined;
     }

    try {

         //Turn the json object of the current user's id and the type of token into a string
         var stringData = JSON.stringify({
             _id: user._id,
             type: type
         });

        //Take the json string and encrypt it with a secret then turn it back into a string
        var encryptedData = cryptojs.AES.encrypt(stringData, secrets.crypto).toString();

        //Take the encryptedData and turn it into a token with a secret
        var token = jwt.sign({
            token: encryptedData
        }, secrets.jwt);

        return token;
    } catch(e) {
        return undefined;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Elastic Beanstalk I believe the preferred way to store keys like this is via environment variables. You can use the command `eb setenv key=value` to set an environment variable. More information about this [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/eb3-setenv.html).

For accessing the AWS API, which you mention in regards to accessing DynamoDB and S3, you would not use keys at all. For this you would assign an IAM instance profile to the EC2 servers created by Elastic Beanstalk. This is documented [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/AWSHowTo.iam.html).

Comment: Is this also a "safe way"

Comment: The `eb setenv` call is going to send the key name and value over an SSL connection to the AWS API, so it is a safe way to set the value. You can also do the same thing via the AWS web console I believe. It is "safe" as long as you restrict access to your AWS account. If you want more security around these values you could look into using the AWS Key Management Service (KMS). You would have to build some support for using that service into your application though, as it isn't tightly integrated with Elastic Beanstalk.

Answer (score -2):

Create a configuration file for all the envoirments like development, production and add all the secret keys init and use anywhere you want.

```
config.json file
{
"development": {
    "Secret1": "Your Secret Here",
    "Secret2": "Your Secret Here",
    "db":{
      //development database settings here
     }
 },
   "production": {
    "Secret1": "Your Secret Here",
    "Secret2": "Your Secret Here",
    "db":{
      //development database settings here
     }
   }
}

var config = require('./config.json');
config.Secret1;
```

Comment: but would I deploy that file with my project during production?

Comment: yes that file should be on the server. You want dont want to put that file on server? That file or secret wont be travelling on the network so its safe to keep the file on server

Comment: Wouldn't that be putting the keys in plain text on the server?

Comment: Restrict the access of amazon AWS to the allowed ips only and loadbalancer. Your keys will be safe

Comment: You can encrypt the keys aswell but the decryption technique should also be on the server so it can decrypt it for use, So its just some extra work of no use

Comment: wouldn't it be pointless to encrypt the keys if the decryption technique is also on the server? I am thinking about just putting my keys in AWS Environment variables. Would this work as well?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133189/discussion-between-asif-saeed-and-connorb).